# The command force Unrecognized command

Tags: batch-file, tfs

I write .bat file, which delete automatically tf workspace. I use command, and I see message: A deleted workspace cannot be recovered.... Are you sure you want to delete the workspace?. And this command wait my answer.

```
tf workspace /delete  blah
```

I try set force, but I see error: Unrecognized command option "force"

```
tf workspace /delete  blah /force
```

So it's possible automatically delete workspace?

Comment: try something like this: `echo y | tf workspace /delete  blah`

Comment: Welcome. If you don't mind please accept this as the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tf workspace /delete /noprompt blah